# *_url not working in rails 4 ActiveRecord Serializer

Tags: model, ruby-on-rails-4.2, active-model-serializers, rails-api

i am getting undefined method:

```
undefined method `url' for TrackSerializer:Class
```

but my aim is to have the url of the related object url in my json response

here is my model:

```
class TrackSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

  attributes :id, :title
  has_many :playlists
  has_one :album

  url :track

end
```

here is what i am trying to achieve in my response:

```
{
    "tracks": [
        {
            "id": 7,
            "title": "True love",
            "playlists_url": "http://localhost:3000/7/playlist",
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: If I'm reading your associations correctly, each Track will have many Playlists. You want to return the array of Playlist urls for each Track?

Comment: yes but what i want is the url instead of the playlists

Comment: But I'm correct in understanding you'll want an array of playlist urls and not just a single url like your example indicates?

Comment: yes, you are 100% correct

Answer (score 3):

I would go ahead and create a PlaylistSerializer that just returns the url for the object:

```
class PlaylistSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :url

  def url
    Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.playlist_url(object)
  end
end
```

Remove `url :track` from your TrackSerializer.

Comment: i have do the above but i am gettig following error: undefined method `playlist_url

Comment: Hmm. URL helpers should be included. Looks like there might be bug though: "https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/770" You might have to hard-code the url (see the section I have commented out)

Comment: The URL should be host-sensitive, though. Personally I'd consider using a gem that implements any of the normalized resource locators.